# How to group duplicate records and then update all members except lowest id for each group?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
|   id    |   name | description  |    publish
    1          B           text              1
    2          B           text2             1
    3          B3          text3             1
    4          B4          text4             1
    5          B5          text              1
```

Two or more records maybe be duplicate in name or description.

I want SQL query find all duplicates and then set `publish = 0` except one!

Something like this algorithm to select:

```
update table 
(set punlish = 0 for all records of each group of dublicate except lowset id in that froup) 
    where (name = name or description   = description)  
          AND  publish = 1
```

For example, after run query I must have this:

```
|   id    |   name | description  |    publish
    1          B           text              1 // not change!
    2          B           text2             0
    3          B3          text3             1
    4          B4          text4             1
    5          B5          text              0
```

Or for this before:

```
|   id    |   name | description  |    publish
    1          B           text               1 
    2          B           text2              1
    3          B3          text               1
    4          B4          text4              1
    5          B5          text5              1
    6          B5          text6              1
    7          B5          text7              1
```

And after:

```
|   id    |   name | description  |    publish
    1          B           text               1 // no change
    2          B           text2              0 
    3          B3          text               0
    4          B4          text4              1
    5          B5          text5              1 // no change
    6          B5          text6              0
    7          B5          text7              0
```

Comment: why dont you handle it at insertion time itself.
like if you gonna insert B in name , first check if its present or not , if present insert with publish=0 else publish=1. Same with description.

Comment: you right ... but I have a big table now full of dublicate records ..I want remove it now!

Comment: @partiz The query I gave below may already be sufficient, but could you post sample data which also shows duplication in the `description` for a given `name` value?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - The second example id=3,description=text is a duplicate (by description) of row id=1.

Comment: @partiz What happens when you have a row that is not a min(id) for name, and should be updated to zero, but it is not the min(id) for a description. In that case, it seems we have a conflicting case. What should the code do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considered table name as `temp1`

```
update temp1 set publish=0 where id in (select x.id from (select a.id from temp1 a ,temp1 b 
where
a.id<>b.id and (a.name=b.name or a.description=b.description)and a.id>b.id 
group by a.id) as x);
```

Check Here : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/19863/1

This will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

using `"pubs"` as table name

```
UPDATE
  pubs
  LEFT JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      MIN(id) minId
    FROM
      pubs
    GROUP BY
      name
  ) minPubs ON
  minPubs.minId = pubs.id
SET
  pubs.publish = 0
WHERE
  minPubs.minId IS NULL;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/54fae/1

Comment: Your answer fails on id=3 as it doesn't consider description as well as name for duplicates.

Comment: The OP did a poor job of showing us _all_ sample data.  This query will work for the samples given, although it may fail in other cases.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Agreed, it wasn't as clear as it could/should have been.

Comment: @Turophile does that make any sense, though? What would the behavior be if there is a duplicate on name, but then that duplicate is the min(id) for the description? This use case makes no sense.

Comment: Yes, not very clear, what to do with the edge cases. I just took it to mean duplicate on name or description, which gave the given result for the given input, but that may not be what the OP really wants. Perhaps we should ask OP?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
update table1 
set publish = 0 
where id in (
  select id from (
  select id 
  from table1 as A
  where 0 < (
    select count(*) 
    from table1 as B
    where (A.name = B.name or A.description = B.description)
    and A.id > B.id 
    )
  ) as temp1 
);
```

Fiddle is here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/414be/1.